# What exactly does AndroidManifest.XML show in my .apk file? My current assignment is to obtain 2 flags

Tags: android, security, penetration-testing, ctf

[screenshot of the AndroidManifest.XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPvy7.png)

I've tried downloading APKtool package to decompile the apk file however I am unable to download any packages due to the restriction of my assignment. Im not sure what else I can do. This .apk file comes from after I ftp into an ip address ( 192.168.147.x ). After i NMAP -A the ip address, only two services show up, SSH and FTP. What should i do?

Comment: The formatting shouldn't be broken like this. Some interesting things in the manifest are "allowCleartextTraffic" and that it apparently enables deeplinking through some url. But I can't find the URL maybe due to the formatting. It also lists all Activities. Maybe one of them includes some insecurities related to intents: https://0xn3va.gitbook.io/cheat-sheets/android-application/intent-vulnerabilities

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.